# Problem with the exemple of veins-lte omnet++ in a runtime

Tags: runtime-error, omnet++, veins, lte

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, sumo 0.21, omnet 4.6 and veins-lte 1.2. 
When I run the heterogenous exemple in veins, I have the following error:

```
<!> Error in module (LteMacUe) scenario.node[1].nic.mac (id=104) at event #2381, t=0.609: H-ARQ TX: fb is not for the pdu in this unit, maybe the addressed one was dropped.
```

how to fix it?

thank.

Comment: Are you running the simulation in Cmdenv, Tkenv, or Qtenv?

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'm running the simulation in Tkenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veins LTE is a rather old project.

From what I understand, Veins LTE 1.3 has a bug that keeps simulations from executing in Tkenv or Qtenv: https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/issues/2

I would recommend trying out the much newer Veins with SimuLTE instead. You can download [Instant Veins with SimuLTE](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/), a virtual machine that already has Veins (currently: Veins 5 alpha 1) and SimuLTE installed and ready to run from the Veins website.

Comment: Thank very much ! i will try to use the virtual machine. Best regards.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm looking for a heterogenous implementation, I want to simulate a car which communicates with both eNode and RSU, do you recommend me to use SimuLte and implement the heterogenous car ?? Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, (as of Veins 5 alpha 1) the easiest way of simulating heterogeneous communication technologies would be to use INET for simulating the Wireless LAN communication, SimuLTE for the mobile broadband connection, and Veins for network node creation/movement/dynamics according to road traffic.